# Ways to Automate excel for reporting on a scheduled basis where pivot tables wont cut it and data is coming from many places?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, vba, automation

I have a problem that I keep on running into and I cant find the answers anywhere online. and please don't flag this as an opinion article because it 100% is not.

I have a fairly complicated excel report that I need to create and then automate. I have data that is dropped on an ftp site in the form of **CSV, tab delimited, json and .xls**. I also have data on **SQL Server** that I need to bring in too. Once I get the data I have to get it organized, and perform metrics on it too (meaning that its not as simple as drag and drop into a single excel file).

Currently I have been using VBA to import most of it into MS Access and then doing complicated queries to get the data mostly how I want it, then I would port it over to excel by linking the queries in excel and getting it automated by calling the file and specifying a macro to update and import in Access/Excel from a scheduled task.

Not only is this sloppy, It also feels unprofessional and like it could blow up on me at any minute.

**Are there any better/cleaner/more straightforward/clearer/safer ways to do this?**

I know the idea of a c# console app but I cant find any good tutorials to get far enough along to get anything accomplished.

Getting all of the Data localized into one server is out of the question unless I write scripts to do it from the ftp site

I know many programmers are anti Access, and anti VBA. Some have good points, others are just trolls. Please post your experiences with automating excel reports for a good **2016 solution**. All of the documentation that is out there is from 2007 and previous and a Good **Modern** answer is nowhere to be found or else people are trying to claim that buying their library/addin is the only solution (those people make me sick that try to thrust crappy code down your throat).

I know about interop, and I know about openxml, and IIS, but I'm not finding great examples online on how to do what I'm aiming for, and Im not even sure if that information is up to date.

So all in all, How do you/would you automate an excel report that needs more finesse than a pivot table, and has data coming from **MANY**  sources on a scheduled basis? And does anyone have a good 2016 example that is not outdated or running on XP still (XP was a great os, but time has come to move on)

preferably C#, VBA, SQL would be the tools used with as little external libraries and addins as possible

Thanks

**Note:**  *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* 
-I am asking about how Automation on excel is done by professionals, and how to do it in a procedural way. I am not asking for books, libraries, or 3rd party tools, or other resources. I am asking for an approach to solve a coding dilemma because I keep on spinning with 100's of lines of code and believe there has to be a more straightforward way.

Comment: Load the data into the database using SSIS?

Comment: VTC - *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* .... You asked us not to flag as an opinion article because it is 100% not. Yet, all you ask is for how we would automate a report with many data sources. There are many ways to skin a cat and many, many opinions based on the languages you prefer to code in.

Comment: I have had really good success with storing the data in a unified database and using MS Query, built directly into Excel.  C# can be used to wake up and "tickle" the data (refresh everything), including pivot tables, charts, etc.  We have dozens of reports that run this way every morning without any human intervention.  MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQL Server Express are all fine choices for the harmonized DB.  My personal favorite is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following methods for long and the most recent successful deployment is December 2015.

Consider the following points for successful automation in scenarios with data from different sources and in different formats:

1. Extraction of data from different sources through

   a. Windows powershell (job scheduling) - fast and useful, 'cause you use MS technologies (OR)

   b. Any other programming language you are comfortable in (OR)

   c. Through SQL agent T-SQL queries (well-defined and well-structured)
   & place all the data in a single folder
2. Transform the data into desired data sets using your preferred method -

   a. Powershell (job scheduling) - best (OR)

   b. Any other language you desire (OR)

   c. VBA for Excel / Access / CSV /Text format
   & I suggest to convert the data sets into .txt format
3. Load these data sets into SQL server / DBMS or wherever for further operations, operate on the data set with your queries and set the jobs as under:

   a. Through SQL agent via T-SQL queries (well-defined and well-structured) (job scheduling)- output to text / excel format (AND)

   b. Use VBA to import and create pivot table / analysis / reports in Excel and schedule through job scheduler
4. Value Addition - 
   Use Powershell extensively for scheduling the jobs, embedding the VBA code, data transactions with SQL server and sending the email (alerts / reports as attachments / notification about success or fails etc).  Please remember to provide sufficient access privileges on network drives / servers which is key to success.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks This is a pretty good explanation of ETL. How would you Update your excel file and Freeze it/remove connections for export/email? **E**-grab from ftp/other site and Load to MSAccess (VBA) **T**-Query data and prep for tables through SQL **L**- link table in excel and present it in human readable way.   **Next** - get it to the End user without massive file or linked tables. I'm guessing that is done through vba too?

Comment: @ALPHAB3TS00P ... "How would you Update .." Pretty easy when the data connections are clearly defined. [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-e11a7a0f-4cea-491c-b6ac-2f4197c6af82)
"E-grab from ftp/other site ....guessing that is done through vba too?" Only for smaller amounts of data usually up to 6 MB.  But for larger amounts of data and unstructrured information, it is always 
'ETL process to SQL server, run T-SQL queries, export to Text / Excel (no need for Access) then use VBA to generate format and present data.'

Answer (score 1):

I understand the emphasis you gave on the many sources part, however my first approach to such a subject is always how to standardize the raw form of the data. I believe that standardization is the golden rule. Which brings the question on how to do it.

On a recent example, I had to make a tool that produces a report based on data available on both an SQL server and online Excel spreadsheets. The solution was to convert all the data in the format I was most comfortable working with, which for me was Excel spreadsheets. Hence, for the data in the SQL Server I produced a script that fed from an online available spreadsheet e.g. on a SharePoint and in turn save the data in the same online location. At this stage the data was in pretty raw form (i.e. no processing, minimal filtering etc.).

Thus having a common online location where my data (Excel spreadsheets and converted SQL data) are available, I produced an add in that fed of from that location. The benefit of this was that the add-in can be distributed to multiple users (which was my prerequisite) and everyone feed of data from the same location.

To summarise:

- Standardize as much as possible raw data form.
- Common data source.
- Do processing of data in language you are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would create a program in C# or Visual Basic (it's personal preference; both use the same .NET features) which imports data in whatever format you require.

Firstly, you can extract data from XLS files by [referencing Excel Interop in your .NET project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Extracting CSV data is not particularly difficult if you use the [TextFieldParser class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx) for a Visual Basic tutorial). This same class will allow you to parse tab-delimited data. JSON-formatted data is more tricky, but [this free, open-source .NET library](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) provides everything you would need in that department.

As for SQL Server, this is apparently quite easy to use with a .NET application (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or just Google it).

The trick is to always extract this data into **the same internal format**, so that you can import it into Excel in the same way after retrieving it.

Your requirements are complex ones, and as such I cannot give a particularly full answer, but hopefully my viewpoint is a useful one...